# increasing primes producing last digits and order of efficiency

Tags: numbers, primes

```
Adding two increasing primes can produce last digits of 0,2,4,6,8: there are six ways to do this,
```

1+9=3+7=0; 3+9=2; 1+3=4;7+9=6;1+7=8.  Of course, 1+9 is equivalent to 9+1.  Efficiency means after finding a large number  of the desired last digit, one has reached the smallest prime in  doing so.  For example, starting at 3,19,23,29,43,59,73,79,83,89,103 I have found ten last digits of 2 by the time I reached 103. Do you think there is an order of efficiency that stays constant for each of the six ways for these last digits?  Which of 1+9, 3+7 and so on will be the
most efficient or the second most efficient or the
least efficient.

Comment: Is this a practical question about computer programming? If not, then it's off-topic for this site.

Comment: It is about primes, is it not?  I just tossed it in to see if anyone would be curious to see if there is a continuing trend of most efficient pairs.  If this is considered off-topic, can you suggest another math website?

Comment: It's definitely off-topic here. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try 2+5=7.  You are forgetting that 2 is prime.  By only using the odd primes you will always get an even result.  For more detail have a look at work on the [Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture).